# One of hosts is available but TNSNAMES style url responds error

Tags: oracle, tnsnames

I'm trying to connect to DB using connecion url:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(TRANSPORT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT=2)(RETRY_COUNT=3)(ADDRESS_LIST=(FAILOVER = on)(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = tcp)(HOST = host1.test.net)(PORT = 1521))(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = tcp)(HOST = host2.test.net)(PORT = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = test)))
```

and receive `ORA-01033` error.
Though it works with one available address:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(TRANSPORT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT=2)(RETRY_COUNT=3)(ADDRESS_LIST=(FAILOVER = on)(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = tcp)(HOST = host2.test.net)(PORT = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = test)))
```

I expected TNSNAMES style allows to select working host in case one of them is down. But it doesn't work

Comment: The failover didn't happen because the network connection to the first host actually succeeded, but happened at a time when the database couldn't accept the *login*. Errors like this, or ORA-01017 for bad username/password - won't trigger a failover at the *network* level. Try again with the listener on host1 disabled, or the database completely stopped and not in the process of stopping. Is this connection string for a RAC configuration?

Comment: @pmdba Thanks! Actually I can't administrate database. And I'm not sure if it's RAC or not. By disabling listener: you mean it should be done on DB side? Or I can manage it via connection url somehow?

Comment: It would have to be on the DB side. If you can't control that, then your specific error situation is just the result of bad timing. It should work correctly if the database on host1 is completely up or completely down. You got the error because the network listener accepted the connection but the database wasn't in a correct state to complete the login. Bad logins won't failover. If you had RAC (one database, multiple hosts) you could use a single "SCAN" DNS address for the cluster and the database servers would handle all of the failover automatically.

Comment: If this is Data Guard, make sure you are using a service that is only available on the primary side. Can you ask someone to verify the service name?